# Daily Operations (how to do excel format #/7)

Tags: r, number-formatting

Having the following data for a sample 7 day week

```
Route  WeeklyOps
DFWLGA  14
LAXJFK  10
MIAORD  4
```

I would like the output to be something like this:

```
Route DailyOps
DFWLGA  2
LAXJFK  1 3/7
MIAORD  4/7
```

In excel you would do custom formatting like this `#/7`

Having been able to find the correct solution

Comment: Are the numbers under `WeeklyOps` like day of the year? You could use a combination of `strptime` and `strftime` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There may be an existing function, but it is easy to make something that will do this

```
WeeklyOps <- c(14, 10, 4)

formatFraction <- function(x, div){
  int <- x %/% div
  rem <- x %% div
  int <- ifelse(int == 0, "", int)
  frac <- ifelse(rem == 0, "", paste0(" ", rem, "/", div))
  paste0(int, frac)
}
formatFraction(WeeklyOps, div = 7)
```